# How does CTAS create files in s3 when we are creating random samples using parition by?

Tags: amazon-s3, presto, amazon-athena

I have data at category level, there are around 12k categories.
I am trying to create random samples from each category in Athena and trying to save them in s3.

If I try to create samples for each category separately it is taking more than 48hrs to run the queries. I am trying to use CTAS but I am not sure how the parquet files are created internally, because number of files in s3 created doesnt match with number of categories.

What could be a better solution?

```
CREATE TABLE dataset_sample
            WITH
            (
             format = 'PARQUET',
             external_location = 'location'
            )
           AS SELECT sampled.product_id
            sampled.ps_category as category
            FROM
            (
                SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ps_category ORDER BY rnd) as rnk
                FROM (
                    SELECT *, RANDOM() AS rnd
                    FROM table2
                    where
                      ps_category like 'DIY & Tools/Hardware/Nails, Screws & Fasteners%'
                    ) bucketed
            ) sampled
            WHERE rnk <= 40000
```

Comment: I guess you need to partition your data by category (`WITH (partitioned_by=ARRAY['category'])` should do this).

Comment: CTAS has a limitation of 100 partitions, I have 12000 categories and CTAS doesnt support this